# Display Cursor in WPF TextBox without Focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there anyway to make it look like a TextBox has focus when it really does not? I would like to display the flashing cursor in a WPF TextBox even though it does not have focus.

***Why do I want to do this?***
We have a system that accepts touch input from more than one user at a time. One of the users has focus and I cant have it jumping between controls. The secondn user input is from an on-screen keyboard. As they type the letters the text is entered in the textbox. It just looks strange for there not to be a cursor.

Comment: My thought is to use animation to create a flashing cursor.  And if it cannot have focus then I assume it cannot be edited so maybe go with a TextBlock as it is a little lighter and faster.

Comment: this looks like a hack waiting to happen: [To be focusable, Focusable and IsEnabled must both be true.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx) `TextBoxBase.IsReadOnlyCaretVisible` may be of interest. Also, skimming dotPeek, a non-hack solution does not look promising.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to show a TextBox but not allow the it to get focus? I'm assuming the input is being processed by another control, but I was just wondering

Comment: I added the "Why" in the question

Answer (score 0):

Well I think You can use animations for your TextBoxs, it will play all the time or at any time you want without being focused, hope it will help.